# смена картинки при наведении на кнопку winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Пришлось поработать с winform, имею хороший вопрос. Как сменить изображение кнопки при наведении и нажатии? Скорее всего это делается через хэндлер mousehover, но хотел бы уточнить подробности. Просто нужна дефолтная смена BackgroundImage.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: Опубликуйте решение и примите его как правильный ответ. Если не хочется, и вопрос уже не актуален, то можете удалить его, чтобы не занимал место :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прошу прощения что не ответил сразу.
Добавил для кнопок просто event hendler'ы MouseLeave и Mouse Enter и в мэйн коде добавил данные строки. Простой код для смены картинки при наведении:

```
private void vkBtn_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.vkBtn.BackgroundImage = global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.vk3x;
}

private void vkBtn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.vkBtn.BackgroundImage = global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.vk_3x;
}
```